# Emojis reactions issue on click

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an emojis reaction features which for now works pretty well. I'm having an issue with my click function. I need to click two times to re-trigger an animation. Any advices on how to fix that ?

Here's the pen : `https://codepen.io/kombolo/pen/Popqyxx`

```
const tag = document.createElement("span");
document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].appendChild(tag);
const emojis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

Array.from(emojis).forEach(function (item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function () {
    tag.innerHTML = "";
    const text = document.createTextNode(item.innerHTML);
    tag.appendChild(text);
    tag.classList.toggle('animated')
  });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are toggling the class, which means you need to click a second time to remove it, try adding a setTimeout that removes it once your animation is finished :

```js
    Array.from(emojis).forEach(function (item) {
      item.addEventListener('click', function () {
        tag.classList.remove("animated");
        tag.innerHTML = "";
        const text = document.createTextNode(item.innerHTML);
        tag.appendChild(text);
        setTimeout(() => tag.classList.add("animated"), 10);
      });
    });
```

Comment: Or to avoid having to time it and have problems when clicking multiple times, `remove` the class, then `add` it back with a `setTimeout` with delay 10ms

Comment: I agree with you this is a better solution

Comment: Maybe you could edit your answer to show that ?

Comment: You got my upvote. Last piece of advice: you wrote your code as a runnable snippet, with your JS in the HTML section. It's not runnable on its own anyway, so you'd better just surround it with triple backticks and `javascript`

Answer (score 0):

Arf yes thanks a lot for this quick answer !!